# Efficient Method to parallelize groupby and agg in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I would like to parallelize the following function and speed up the groupby process:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b'], 'B': ['e1', 'e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4', 'e2'], 'C':[[1,2,3], [4,1,5], [2,5,1], [6,2,6], [7,1,3], [7,5,8]]})
df = df.groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False).agg({'C': sum})
```

I have tried the following parallel function but it is not decreasing the time taken:

```
from functools import partial
import multiprocessing as mp
import os

def applyParallel(dfGrouped, func, *args):
    p=mp.Pool(os.cpu_count())
    result=p.map(partial(func, *args), [group for name, group in dfGrouped])
    p.close()
    return(result)

def aggregate_fun(data):
    data = data.groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False).agg({'C': sum})
    return data

df1 = df.groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False)

df2 = applyParallel(df1, aggregate_fun)
df_grouped = pd.concat(df2, axis=0)
```

How can I parallelize or decrease the time taken for the above function, i have around 3 million rows and it takes a lot of time.

Comment: I think you can check [dask groupby](https://examples.dask.org/dataframes/02-groupby.html#Groupby-Aggregations) for already implemented parallel groupby operation.

Comment: Dask groupby is also taking similar time

Answer (score 0):

You may decrease the time requested for groupby when you use single column only, for example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b'], 'B': ['e1', 'e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4', 'e2'], 'C':[[1,2,3], [4,1,5], [2,5,1], [6,2,6], [7,1,3], [7,5,8]]})
df['new_col'] = df['A']+df['B']

df = df.groupby(['new_col'], as_index=False).agg({'C': sum})
```

Processing time = 2.6 ms instead of 3.5 ms with ['A', 'B'] and creating of new column is quite cheap (0.25 ms).

Comment: Considering that I have to split the columns again, the time difference is significant. 
Do we have a method to parallelize the operation, probably that could reduce the time significantly?

Comment: @TayyabRahmani well, then you could try pandarallel solution - [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/pandaral-lel-a-simple-and-efficient-tool-to-parallelize-your-pandas-operations-on-all-your-cpus-bb5ff2a409ae). I haven't checked it personally, but looks promising.

Comment: parallel_apply doesn't work with aggregation, it depends on rows being independent which is not the case in groupby